# Get caption for Ligthbox in Imagelightbox from figcaption

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using Imagelightbox from here https://osvaldas.info/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly as a lightbox and trying to achive to alter the source for image caption. By default Imagelightbox uses die Alt-Attribute for his caption.

My initial piece of html looks like this:

```
<figure>
    <a href="file.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="lightbox-1" data-imagelightbox="lightbox-1">
        <img src="file.jpg" alt="foo">
    </a>
    <figcaption>bar</figcaption>
</figure>
```

So Imagelightbox would show "foo" as caption, but I want to get the content of the figcaption as caption for the lightbox.

Ist this possible without altering the alt-attribute itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lack of a configuration option for that I have override the captionOn-function in my javascript. Perhaps it helps someone:

```
var instanceImagelightbox = $(selectorImagelightbox).imageLightbox({
    onLoadEnd: function () {
        //Override original captionOn() to use figcaption instead of alt-attr
        captionOn = function() {
            var description = $( 'a[href="' + $( '#imagelightbox' ).attr( 'src' ) + '"]' ).next('figcaption').text();
            if( description.length > 0 )
                $( '<div id="imagelightbox-caption">' + description + '</div>' ).appendTo( 'body' );
        };
        captionOn();            
    }
});
```